# Submit POST method without a form?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a button with a similar functionality to "Follow" buttons in social networks. The thing is I need to refresh the page when the user clicks the button since the page content largely depends whether the user is following or not.

I could submit the "follow" with ajax and reload the page when ajax responds. Is it possible to submit data with POST without AJAX (like forms do)?

Comment: Er...why can't you just use a form? You know you can have multiple forms on a page right?

Comment: The thing is that there is no need for user input. I could use a form with hidden input fields and show the submit button. I can't think of any problem with doing this but it just doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: Of *course* there is user input. The user clicking a button saying they want to follow. And yes, you would use one hidden field. That's exactly the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery you can do something like

```
$.post('pageurl.php', {"variable1": "Value1", "Variable2": "Value2"}, function(datareturn){});
```

And handle it from serverside like normal

```
$var1 = $_POST["varriable1"];
```

Comment: You can do without ajax using a target iframe

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data to be submitted, a regular link can submit data as well.

This, for example, submits the search term `this and that`

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=this+and+that
```

Comment: yes but this would submit with `GET` not `POST` as specified in the quesiton, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @jidma -- True, but sometimes proposing a possible alternative lets the OP re-think possibilities.  Often the question being asked isn't actually the problem that needs solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your form dynamically and then remove it:

```
function postjs (to,method, p) {
  var myForm = document.createElement("form");
  myForm.method=method;
  myForm.action = to ;
  for (var k in p) {
    var myInput = document.createElement("input") ;
    myInput.setAttribute("name", k) ;
    myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
    myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;
  myForm.submit() ;
  document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;
}
```

and call it:

```
postjs('target.php','post',{field1:'value1',field2:'value2'})
```

Comment: he stated in the question `Is it possible to submit data with POST without AJAX (like forms do)`

Comment: I can't see any reason why AJAX couldn't work in this scenario, but oh well.